# Помогите с переносом с Webclienta на httpclient c#

Tags: c#, httpclient, webclient

Переписываю код
в старом используется WebClient

```
byte[] data = wc.DownloadData(server + php);
```

В том что переписываю использую

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient()
```

Но в конструкторе нет похожего.

Помогите, пожалуйста

Участок кода

```
//** HTTP CLIENT **//
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        //****//
        string ua = ("Mozilla/6.0 (Windows NT6.1; WOW64; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0)like Gecko");
        string server = ("http://xxx.xxx.xxx:80");
        string cookie = ("");
        string php = ("***.php");
        //****//
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders
        .UserAgent
        .TryParseAdd(ua);
        //****//
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", cookie);
        //****//
        try
        {
            byte [] data = client.**DownloadData**(server + php);
        }
        catch { }
```

Comment: в конструкторе нет, а что в методах?

Comment: WebClient использует для этого конструктор

Comment: ну HttpClient видимо не использует, значит это как то по другому классу передаваться должно

Comment: Эм, о каком конструкторе идет речь? Чет я не вижу где либо `new(.....)` (использование конструктора). О чем речь то? Я так понимаю, по этому `**DownloadData**` - речь про получение байт? Если да, то аналогом будет `byte[] data = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(server + php);`. Про `Cookie` я советую тоже изучить вопрос, ибо они там устанавливаются/получаются при помощи `CookieContainer`, а не заголовки.